# How is the Power Attack feat's bonus damage calculated?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, damage

I'm a little confused with how Pathfinder explains [Power Attack](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/power-attack-combat/). I get the feat allows melee weapons to deal +2 damage, plus another 2 for every increment of 4 BAB and an additional 50% more for two-handed weapons.

Ex: BAB +12 with Great Sword = 12 bonus damage ([2x4] + 50%)

Is this added in addition to the +1.5 Str modifier bonus for using a two-handed melee weapon?

Ex: Str mod +4, BAB +12 with Great Sword = 15 bonus damage (12 feat + 6 Str mod [4 x 1.5])

Answer (score 5):

### Yes, it stacks with your str bonus

[Power attack](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/power-attack-combat/) says:

> Benefit: You can choose to take a –1 penalty on all melee attack rolls and combat maneuver checks to gain a **+2 bonus on all melee damage rolls**. This bonus to damage is increased by half (+50%) if you are making an attack with a two-handed weapon, a one handed weapon using two hands, or a primary natural weapon that adds 1-1/2 times your Strength modifier on damage rolls. This bonus to damage is halved (–50%) if you are making an attack with an off-hand weapon or secondary natural weapon.
>
> When your base attack bonus reaches +4, and every 4 points thereafter, the penalty increases by –1 and the bonus to damage increases by +2.

This means that at BAB +1 (Prerequisite is BAB +1) you take -1 to hit and get +2 to damage (+3 for 2h), at BAB +4 you take -2 to hit and get +4 to damage (+6 for 2h), at BAB +8 you take -3 to hit and get +6 to damage (+9 for 2h), and so on.

If you happen to have 20 str (+5 modifier) attacking with power attack, you get your normal modifier with 1h weapons and 1.5 times your modifier with 2h weapons (+7). Example, at BAB +4 with 20 str, you get a total bonus to attack of +7 (BAB +4, +5 str, -2 power attack), and a total bonus to damage of +9 with 1h weapons (+5 str, +4 power attack) or +13 with 2h weapons (+7 str, +6 power attack).